# google api for searching different places round me in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hai friends I am new to Iphone programing ,in my project i want search different places like hospitals ,heathers ,fire stations ,and I just give the place and radius as inputs to URL ,so this which is the best API.or give me the url.

Comment: Have a look at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Google Places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) a go.

If you are not able (or willing) to comply with Google's terms you may consider using [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) instead.